# Why is my menu item resulting in a file not found error in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I have a new component called com_location. It has a single model, 
controller, and view. If I go to the page URL manually (i.e. 
mysite.com/index.php?option=com_location&view=location) it displays my 
view correctly (all the view does right now is display a table 
containing a bunch of records from the database.)

However, when I add a menu item of type Internal Link, it doesn't 
work. I select Internal Link, then Locations -> Location - >Default 
Layout (my only choice.) I set the title to Find a Community, and the 
alias to find-a-community. The generated link shown in the Link input 
field (non-editable) is index.php?option=com_location&view=location - 
exactly the same URL I can type in manually.

When I go to my front-end, the Find a Community link is there; 
clicking on it produces the URL mysite.com/find-a-community, and 
instead of my component, I get an error message: "The requested URL / 
find-a-community was not found on this server."

I do have search engine-friendly URLs enabled in the global 
configuration. 
Help?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you disable SEF urls does it work? If so, you will need to write a router.php file

http://docs.joomla.org/Routing

Comment: I have a router file. As it turned out, I had forgotten to rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess. That fixed it.